# No <br> by default in tinymce

Tags: tinymce

i've tried many things I've found here on stack, but none seem to help with the

```
<p> text </p>
<br>
```

Problem.

What I'm asking is how to switch off by default the `<br>` making by tinymce.

I know shift-enter does the trick, but I have a user generated site, and having to edit each tinymce input... Well takes too much time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```html
echo str_replace('<br>',' ',$variable_that_echoing);
```

Comment: That doesn't do it, and it's not a nice way of doing it.

I keep my tinymce input in a database, don't think this will work, neither will it help returing the variable.

Comment: By the way i suggest you to use CKEDITOR.

Comment: No.I use this and i never have this.Try to use it and if it does your work keep this.